# Как слушать определенный чат?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot, python-3.8

У меня есть бот, а бот работает в нескольких чатов, как сделать так, чтобы мне выводилось Message.ID в определенном чате ?

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать условие типа `if msg.chat.id == chat_id: print(msg.message_id)`